# Knockout collection link binding error

Tags: javascript, html, mvvm, knockout.js

Here is my Knockout ViewModel

```
$(document).ready(
    function () {

        var Crime = function (CaseNumber, DateOfIncident, Description) {
            this.CaseNumber = CaseNumber;
            this.DateOfIncident = DateOfIncident;
            this.Description = Description;
        }

        var crimes = function (items) {
            var self = this;
            //Data
            self.items = ko.observableArray(items)

            //operations
            self.addCrime = function () {
                if ($("#AddCrimeForm").valid()) {
                    self.crime = new Crime($("#CaseNumber").val(), $("#DateOfIncident").val(), $("#Description").val());
                    //var JSONObj = { CaseNumber: $("#CaseNumber").val(), DateOfIncident: $("#DateOfIncident").val(), Description: $("#Description").val() };
                    self.items.push(this.crime);

                    $("#CaseNumber").val("");
                    $("#DateOfIncident").val("");
                    $("#Description").val("");
                }
            }

            self.removeCrime = function (item) {
                self.items().remove(item);
            }

        }

        var initialData = new Array();
        ko.applyBindings(crimes(initialData), $("#CrimeList")[0])
    }
);
```

Here is my View, in HTML:

```
<form id="AddCrimeForm">
    <div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-11">Add a crime incident to the list</div>
                    <div class="col-lg-1">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" onclick="addCrime()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="Id" name="Id" type="hidden" value="">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="CaseNumber">Case Number</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Case Number field is required." id="CaseNumber" name="CaseNumber" type="text" value="">
                                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="CaseNumber" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="DateOfIncident">Date Of Incident</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input class="form-control text-box single-line valid" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Date of Incident field is required." id="DateOfIncident" name="DateOfIncident" type="date" value="">
                                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="DateOfIncident" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="Description">Description</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <textarea class="form-control text-box multi-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Description field is required." id="Description" name="Description"></textarea>
                                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Description" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<table class="table table-striped table-hover " id="CrimeList">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Case Number</th>
            <th>Date of Incident</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: $data.CaseNumber" class="col-lg-2">Column content</td>
            <td data-bind="text: $data.DateOfIncident" class="col-lg-2">Column content</td>
            <td data-bind="text: $data.Description" style="text-wrap: normal" class="col-lg-7">Column content</td>
            @*<td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>*@
            <td style="text-align: center" class="col-lg-1">
                <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeCrime()"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Remove</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The error I get when adding an item relates to the binding of the "Remove" link in the table, and is as follows:

> Unhandled exception at line 58, column 363 in
>   `http://localhost:49803/Scripts/KnockOut/knockout-3.0.0.js`
>
> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property
>   'removeCrime' of undefined or null reference

Now, I'm not sure what the problem here is, since I am supposed to be binding to the root, since the removeCrime method resides in the root of the ViewModel?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the removeCrime function on the window object, as crimes function is being executed in the global scope, and this points to the window.

Try using new keyword when setting a viewModel.This will create new object and set it as this.
You should also attach the add method to the window if you want to call it outside of knockout.
Another error is that you are calling remove() on an JS Array not on observable Array.
Here is the working code:

```
$(document).ready(
  function () {

    var Crime = function (CaseNumber, DateOfIncident, Description) {
        this.CaseNumber = CaseNumber;
        this.DateOfIncident = DateOfIncident;
        this.Description = Description;
    }

    var crimes = function (items) {
        var self = this;
        //Data
        self.items = ko.observableArray(items)

        //operations
        window.addCrime = function () {
            if ($("#AddCrimeForm")) {
                crime = new Crime($("#CaseNumber").val(), $("#DateOfIncident").val(), $("#Description").val());
                //var JSONObj = { CaseNumber: $("#CaseNumber").val(), DateOfIncident: $("#DateOfIncident").val(), Description: $("#Description").val() };
                self.items.push(this.crime);

                $("#CaseNumber").val("");
                $("#DateOfIncident").val("");
                $("#Description").val("");
            }
        }

        self.removeCrime = function (item) {
            self.items.remove(item);
        }
    }

    var initialData = new Array();
    ko.applyBindings(new crimes(initialData), $("#CrimeList")[0])
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I will check it out and get back to you.  My JS really rusty (a few years since I did anything in JS) so I appreciate the advice.

Comment: "Another error is that you are calling remove() on an JS Array not on observable Array".  I agree with this.

Comment: "Try using new keyword when setting a viewModel.This will create new object and set it as this. You should also attach the add method to the window if you want to call it outside of knockout."  Coming from a CSharp background I am having difficulty with context and scoping in JavaScript.  Would appreciate it if you could recommend good reading material on the subject.

Comment: this (;) should be helpful : http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/

Answer (score 0):

I check your code and according to me you are missing the real power of knockout. If you are using knockout than i think there is no need to access values of input fields using jquery selectors.

I have created a js fiddle, check this:

[demo fiddle](http://jsbin.com/pomusula/1/edit?output)

And the javascript code will look something like:

```
function crimeRecord(data)
{
   var self = this;

   self.caseNumber =  data.CaseNumber;
   self.dateOfIncident = data.DateOfIncident;
   self.description = data.Description;
}

//Main view model
function viewModel()
{
   var self = this;

   self.crimeRecords = ko.observableArray();

   self.newCrimeRecord = ko.observable(new crimeRecord({}));

   self.addRecord = function(){
     self.crimeRecords.push(self.newCrimeRecord());
     self.newCrimeRecord(new crimeRecord({}));
   };

   self.removeRecord = function(record){
     self.crimeRecords.remove(record);
   };
}

$(function(){
  ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
});
```

**Edit - 1**

As you mention doubt in your comment regarding to jquery validation, there is no need to rewrite any validation logic you can use jquery validation with this viewmodel. The following is the one way to use it:

```
   .... 

   self.addRecord = function(){
     if($("form").valid())
     {   
       self.crimeRecords.push(self.newCrimeRecord());
       self.newCrimeRecord(new crimeRecord({}));
     }
     else
      $("form").showErrors();
   };

   ...
```

Or you can use [Knockout Validation](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation).

Comment: Thanks.  Will take a look and get back to you

Comment: I appreciate your comments with regards to the correct usage of Knockout, however, I am not sure what the implications of this will be with regards to the unobtrusive JQuery validation that is supposed to take place on the new record fields.  Only when the new record fields are validated can the record be added to the list.  Rewriting validation is currently not an option.

Comment: Also, what I don't understand is why you need to create the newCrimeRecord property that will only be used temporarily upon record creation?  I understand that it eliminates the need for the use of JQuery to access input field values.  But it seems like a bit of a hack to me - not really in keeping with the intent of object orientation.  Perhaps clarify this or link to a resource which explains this?

Comment: newCrimeRecord property is just to hold the new record `object` which is going to add in the list, now if you want to do anything before or after with the newly created object like validation or anything else than its easy to do with a single property in hand. And i feel there is no hack in this.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: It contributed to the final solution, but did not solve my problem 100%.  As indicated above it should work with the current validation mechanisms that I have in place without me having to rewrite any validation.  I will post the code for the solution I opted to go with soon.  I did however give you a +1 for the contribution :)